# xamarin forms UWP tablet app windows 10 clicking on 2nd textbox closes keyboard

Tags: xamarin, uwp, textbox, keyboard, focus

We are doing User acceptance testing on a Xamarin Forms UWP app targeting windows 10 tablet.  We are finding that when the user clicks on a textbox to enter data the soft keyboard appears as expected.  However, when the user then clicks into the next textbox to enter a second required piece of data, the soft keyboard hides/closes.  This results in the user having to double hit the second textbox (and any more than might need to be filled).  The first click hides the keyboard, the second then causes the keyboard to reappear.  To say the least this is not a good user experience.  I'm guessing maybe the focus of the second is firing before the lost focus of the first?  Has anyone else observed this behavior and is there any easy fix?  As may want to target both Android and Windows I'm hoping for a simple solution but maybe UWP just does has some problems?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I tested on the windows phone emulator 15063, click the second Editor control will not hide the soft keyboard. Please detail your issue, provide the relative code snippet, testing device details and so on.

Comment: This problem exists on Windows 10 Tablets.  Do not think testing on a phone emulator is this same thing.  I have told the users that to get around this problem, they open the keyboard by tapping on it so stay up continually until they are done inputting.  This just seems to be the behavior on tablets.  I recently experienced it on a Samsung Tab 4 as well.